# SIGTERM on starting a standby HDFS HA namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, high-availability

I had a non-HA enabled HDFS cluster which I wanted to reconfigure to be HA. I followed these steps:

1. Switch off the only namenode (N1) and all the datanodes.
2. Update all the nodes with the new HA configuration.
3. Start the journal nodes.
4. Create the second namenode (N2).
5. Run `hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby` on the new namenode N2. Note that I had to first start the old namenode N1 in order for that to work.
6. Run `hdfs namenode -initializeSharedEdits` on the main namenode N1.

After all that I tried to start the new namenode N2. It resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Which Hadoop version you are using? Are you using any packaged Hadoop like Cloudera or Hortonworks?

Comment: 2.7.1. Nope, just a standalone Hadoop.

Comment: What do you mean by "Standalone Hadoop" - Apache Hadoop or Single Node Hadoop?
Also, Can you paste the full Namenode log (particularly stacktrace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the cluster was configured with automatic failover with Zookeeper, but the Zookeeper nodes were not setup. The issue was gone after setting up the Zookeeper cluster.